# Search through using a for loop of an arraylist of another class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

I'm using an ArrayList to plot the lat/long co-ordinates of a set of data onto a google map.

The problem I'm having is there will be a lot of variables. Around 60 in total. I don't think I should just list them all like below. I guess putting them in another class (data.class or something) would be better.

How would I go about doing this and then using the for loop to plot the coords in the mainactivity.class?

```
    var.add(new LatLng(5, 6));      //unique coords
    var.add(new LatLng(5, 9));
    var.add(new LatLng(4, 5));
    var.add(new LatLng(3, 5));
    var.add(new LatLng(2, 1));
    var.add(new LatLng(5, 1));
    ... // x50


    for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++) {   //for loop to add the LatLng data to the arrayList
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(var.get(i)));                              

}
```

}}

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve. Do you know all of these coordinates beforehand, or will they be dynamic? Also, will they all the the same (as above)? Describe your situation a bit more maybe.

Comment: I am plotting to a google map fragment a set of 60 unique co-ordinates. The arrayList holds these latLng coords, and the for loop adds it to the array. .position plots them to the map fragment. I just want to basically have a smaller mainactivity. I don't think writing 60 different var.adds is a good idea!

Comment: How are you getting these latand long?

Comment: If they are never going to change, frankly hardcoding them isn't all that terrible. Just create a method "addCoordinates()", fill them in that method and return the filled ArrayList (you should never have so much unecessary code in the main to begin with). A more "correct" (as far as what a professor might want or something) thing to do, would be to have these values stored in a file, and read them. Example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html